# front-end doesn't work when deploy the mern stack to heroku

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, heroku, create-react-app

The client-side is build with create-react-app and the backend is with the express, node.js, and MongoDB. It works locally, but when I deploy to Heroku just the backend works...

index.js

```
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client', 'build')));

  +app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    -app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
       res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'));
     });
  });
}
```

package.json in the server side

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "heroku-postbuild": "cd client && npm install --only=dev && npm install && npm run build"
  },
```

package.json in the client side

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000",
```

also, my mongoose on MongoLab works fine and add it to Heroku
BTW, when I push to Heroku it seems everything works fine. I mean it navigates to client-side and installs and build the package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

moved the `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client', 'build')));` before the app.use(error) and error handlign function then it works